# Cannot access API with correct username and password(c#-HttpClient)-Unauthorized Request

Tags: c#, api, httprequest

i am trying an api and receive data. i got the api username and password but when im trying to connect i get an unauthorized request. i thing something is wrong with my request-header -authentication.
here is my code:

```
using ApiData;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GetDataFromApi
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string uri1 = "https://api.intrinio.com/companies?ticker=AAPL";
            ConnectToApi newapi = new ConnectToApi("username", "password", uri1);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public class ConnectToApi
        {

            public string Username { get; set; }
            public string Password { get; set; }
            public string Request_url { get; set; }

            public ConnectToApi(string username, string password, string url)
            {
                this.Username = username;
                this.Password = password;
                this.Request_url = url;
                GetAPIToken(Username, Password, Request_url);

            }

            private static async void GetAPIToken(string userName, string password, string apiBaseUri)
            {
                try
                {


                    using (var client = new HttpClient())
                    {
                        //setup client
                        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiBaseUri);
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{userName}:{password}")));
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


                        //send request
                        var responseMessage = await client.GetStringAsync(apiBaseUri);



                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

if you have any comments on my code i would love to hear it.

thanks.

lidor

Comment: It worked for me - which means you should immediately change your password.

Answer (score 0):

This might Help

you need to get RestSharp for this to work

```
var client = new RestClient("https://api.intrinio.com/companies?ticker=AAPL");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("authorization", "Basic MGU0NWIxZmIwZDFlMGNkMDEzY2Y2Y2I5MmRlNjk2N2M6MjNjYjM3OTQ3ZmFmMjQ0OWI1MWRjMWQ1NGU2ZGE1Zjc=");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

and you can try to convert it to an object by

```
 try
        {
            dynamic x = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response.Content, new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings() { NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore });
            return x;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            return null;
        }
```

and i do recommend of using http://json2csharp.com/
to create your C# Object
**More Information**

To get the Value that is used for authorization you can use this method

```
 public static string Base64Encode(string key)
 {
    var value = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
    return System.Convert.ToBase64String(value);
 }
```

to get the exact value make sure the username and password are concatenated, (username first , password second) and then passed to the method

Comment: thanks for the help. in the "request.AddHeader("authorization", "Basic MGU0NWIxZmIwZDFlMGNkMDEzY2Y2Y2I5MmRlNjk2N2M6MjNjYjM3OTQ3ZmFmMjQ0OWI1MWRjMWQ1NGU2ZGE1Zjc=")" line i should put the username and password together?

Comment: That code contains your username and password, they are URL 64 Bit base encode, if you do decode on authorization vale you can see it is your username and password,

Comment: If the answer was helpful please accept it, so others can use it with confidence